# MS SQL Server generates duplicate tables when importing an Excel file

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008

Anyone knows why a duplicate table will be generated when using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to import an Excel file? For example, a table named LN$LN appears after the original table named LN$

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you describe your steps in running the import wizard - e.g. are you using the Excel provider or are you indirecting via e.g. ODBC?

Comment: 1. Data Source : I chose Microsoft Excel

2.Destination : SQL Server Native Client 10.0
   Server name : (local)
   Authentication : Use Windows Authentication
   DataBase : I chose my the one to which I wanted to import the table

3. I selected Copy data from one or more tables or views

Comment: Are there any add-ins functioning like the import wizard for MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a hidden sheets in your excel 
can you make a try like below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But there are no hidden sheets.

Comment: can you copy the data in to another excel file and try it again? ideally it should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Was just having an issue similar to this and then noticed the following in the excel spreadsheet I had been given. There was an entire duplicate of the data set hiding in the collapsed rows here only visible by the number color change and extra line. Oddly, unhide and cell height did not seem to work on this, but I was able to expand them back out and delete them by selecting above and below and double-clicking over it (just like you can for the column width to expand to fit).

[image: excel screenshot of hidden rows]

If anyone is experiencing duplicate or unexpected data appearing during import check for something like this as well. Note that it can also appear in the middle (it does not have to be at the end) as I found several of these in the file I was given.